# Unknown action The action 'show' could not be found for MicropostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial continuously building our Sample App, and currently dont have 'show' defined in the MicropostsController, what code should we insert intot he MicropostsController or anywhere else in our MVC framework to fix this error?

When we click on 'delete' the micropost in our feed, we get the "Unknown action The action 'show' could not be found for MicropostsController" error.

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
      @micropost.destroy
      redirect_back_or root_path
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that you have included jquery_ujs.js .
check your application.js and make sure "//= require jquery_ujs" was exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because either JavaScript in your browser is disabled (f.i. via script block), or like SeasonHuang already wrote, jquery_ujs.js is not properly loaded.
If you invoke `rake routes` you will see something like:

```
GET  /microposts/:id  Microposts#show
DELETE  /microposts/:id  Microposts#destroy
```

So the path to show and destroy is the same. They differ in HTTP method. But as HTML forms cannot send DELETE requests, we must do with JavaScrip. Without that you will make GET request to show method which is not yet defined in your controller.